# Bulk loading data into Virtuoso database

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, openlink-virtuoso

I am new to Virtuoso and I want to bulk load data (some `.ttl` files placed in a directory) into Virtuoso, so I can perform SPARQL queries on the graph. So far, I am confused with the process. Here's what I found:

1. define the data directory in `Virtuoso.ini`
2. run this script in iSQL:

   ```
   ld_dir("path_name",'*.*'graph_name);
   rdf_loader_run();
   ```

However, I don't know how to define my directory in `Virtuoso.ini` or if I need to do anything else since the doc is very confusing. If we assume that my file is in this directory: `E:\git\Virtuoso Data\ttls` How do I bulk load the files (how to define the path in `Virtuoso.ini`,...)?

Comment: what exactly is not clear? I mean, everything is explained in the docs: http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtBulkRDFLoader - so what is missing here?

Comment: @UninformedUser I don't know how to define the files first in Virtuoso.ini

Comment: I don't get what you do not understand. Did you read the text in the link? Especially the " Prerequisites" part? The second bullet point? I mean, it's explained what to do, just add the directories to the `DirsAllowed` param in the `[Parameters]` section of the ini file. It's as usual a comma separated list

Comment: @UninformedUser now I added the DirsAllowed parameter like this: DirsAllowed   = ., ../vad, E:\git\Virtuso Data\ttls
and I get this error:
SQLState: 42000

Message: FA003: Access to 'E:gitVirtuso Data tls' is denied due to access control in ini file

Comment: Look at the directory named in the error message, `E:gitVirtuso Data tls`. Note that it's missing directory separator slashes. Change your backslashes (`\ `) to solidus a/k/a forward-slashes (`/`), that is `E:/git/Virtuso Data/ttls`. (Also note, possible typo in what you said, and/or in your actual directory name? `Virtuso` is usually `Virtuoso`).

Comment: I also see a missing comma in your "script", before `graph_name` ... and I have to wonder whether that's literally and exactly the script you'll be running, or you're giving us pseudocode to debug. If the latter, that's not usually successful. If the former, you'll need to localize those values.